# Android WebView can't get viewWidth after the first layout

Tags: android, html, webview

In my Android Application, I used one html page.When I am try to call html page. It gives me error like

```
 W/webcore(23533): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout
```

Here XML file with webview for load html page in Android

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webViewMyBook"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

here code for display html page in webview

```
public class MyBookActivity extends Activity {
Context myContext;
GeneralHelper objHelper;

WebView myBookWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    System.gc();

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    setContentView(R.layout.my_book_layout);

    myContext = this;

    objHelper = new GeneralHelper(myContext);

    myBookWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewMyBook);
    myBookWebView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFCA9"));

    myBookWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    myBookWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    myBookWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    final JavaScriptHandler objScriptHandler1 = new JavaScriptHandler(
            myContext, MyBookActivity.this);

    myBookWebView.addJavascriptInterface(objScriptHandler1,
            "AndroidFunction");

    myBookWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message,
                final android.webkit.JsResult result) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext())
                    .setMessage(message)
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok,
                            new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    result.confirm();
                                }
                            }).setCancelable(true).show();

            return true;
        };
    });

    myBookWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/mybook.html");
}
 }
```

Comment: Show us your code and the xml layout file.

Answer (score 0):

I canceled the call of addJavascriptInterface.
In this case everything is works correctly.

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MyBookActivity extends Activity {

    Context myContext;
//  GeneralHelper objHelper;

    WebView myBookWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        System.gc();

        requestWindowFeature( Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        setContentView(R.layout.my_book_layout);

        myContext = this;

//      objHelper = new GeneralHelper(myContext);

        myBookWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webViewMyBook);
        myBookWebView.setBackgroundColor( Color.parseColor( "#FFFCA9" ));

        myBookWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        myBookWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        myBookWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

//      final JavaScriptHandler objScriptHandler1 = new JavaScriptHandler(myContext, MyBookActivity.this);

//      myBookWebView.addJavascriptInterface(objScriptHandler1, "AndroidFunction");

        myBookWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            @Override
            public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message,
                    final android.webkit.JsResult result) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext())
                        .setMessage( message )
                        .setPositiveButton( android.R.string.ok, new AlertDialog.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick( DialogInterface dialog, int which ) {
                                result.confirm();
                            }
                        } ).setCancelable(true).show();

                return true;
            };
        });

        myBookWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/mybook.html");
    }

}
```

mybook.html in assets folder

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css" />
    <title>Insert title here</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <H1>TEST.HTML</H1>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Without JavaScriptHandler, How can I call function of android in HTML

Comment: I have no code of the JavaScriptHandler class. I simply try to localize the issue.